# How can set of nilpotent matrix be connected?

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology

By Jordan decomposition, every nilpotent matrix is similar to block diagonal matrix $N_{i}$, where $N_{i}$ are the shift matrix, except the zero matrix. The zero matrix cannot be similar to any shift matrix at all. So how can the set of nilpotent matrix connected at all?